# ASPNET CORE 1.1.1 missing NUGet library when published to shared hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have `ASPNet Core 1.1.1` web application running fine at my local development environment. When I published it to a shared hosting using the visual studio "Publish" functionality I get following error on some view pages where I referenced `@using NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3` library

Following is the error message

> One or more compilation references are missing. Possible causes include a missing 'preserveCompilationContext' property under 'buildOptions' in the application's project.json.
>   The type or namespace name 'NuGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   @using NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3
>   ProcessShiftViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ToJson' and no extension method 'ToJson' accepting a first argument of type 'ProcessShiftViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
```

Following is part of my project.json

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
},
"runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
        "System.GC.Server": true
    }
},
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

Following is my global.json

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
}
```

The deployment environment is shared hosting provided by SmarterAsp.net hosting. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3 is part of the .Net Framework 4.6.1 . Installing on my development environment did not help. I was using a Json serializer from this library. I found a work around and stop using this library. Here is an example

With NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3 library code was

```
       var data = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
```

Replaced it with following

```
        var data =  ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
```

Please note I was using Knockout. If you are not using Knocout there are other serializers available. You can also try to do something like following (will generate slightly differnt result though)

```
 var data =   @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Content));
```